# How to add excludes to ngroute in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute

I'm using `ngroute` to define url mappings to controllers.

How can I add excludes to the routes? Example:

```
when(!"/test1*" && !"test2*") {
  template:...
  controller:...
}
```

So here I'm trying to exclude any `$location.path()` that starts with either `test1` or `test2`. Is that possible?

Comment: this doesn't make any sense.  routes aren't global, they are either matched or not.  what are you trying to achieve by defining a match that isn't a match?

Comment: Because I want to map urls dynamically: map any url to a specific controller, except(!) if the path starts with `/test1` or `/test2`, which should then be mapped to a different path.

Comment: so having a route for `/test1` or `/test2` would automatically make them not match anything else....  again, routes are not global.  unless you have an `.otherwise` clause, if there isn't a `.when` for it, it won't match.

Comment: so the answer to your question is, no, what you are trying to do isn't possible, but it also isn't necessary.